# How can I get the dependencies of an MVC controller I'm calling from an angular module?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I need to be able to call a controller endpoint from an angular module. At the moment, I've got the controller endpoint being hit, but it falls over because `locationRepository` is null.

```
[HttpGet, Route("{locationId}")]
    public async Task<string> GetSimulcastUrl(int locationId)
    {
        var location = await _locationRepository.GetLocationById(locationId, false, "en-GB");

        //return result of the above
    }


angular.module('app.services').service('locationService',
[
  '$http', function ($http) {

    this.simulcastUrl = (locationId) => {
      const request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${apiUrl}/Simulcast/GetSimulcastUrl`,
        params: {
            locationId: locationId
        }
      };

      return $http(request);
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Sir! have you initialized this _locationRepository this is not an angular problem. Its on server side where you are writing code to access it.

Comment: There's a constructor that initialises these properties, but the request is forcing me to use a parameterless constructor. If I don't have one, I get an error in the console.